# MySQL query from different databases in time to output in one graph

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures, highcharts

I've build 2 different databases:
1 - temperature measure each 5 minutes
2 - temperature forecast for each 3 hours

I would like to get a 12 hour data of measurements and forecast in one (highcharts) graph.
In the graph, the x bar needs to just display each hour, and the Y bar the temperature.

With php, I can get the 2 separate datastructures, and put them all together, but I would like to do this more dynamicaly by making a sql query with a time dependacy, so I could query for 1 hour, or 24 hours and still get a nice graph.
This would be easy with 2 databases that have the same structure, 
but that's not going to happen when I'm into play :)

Database 1:

```
id  created_on          timestamp           temp
1   2014-01-04 17:15:12 2014-01-04 17:15:02 23.75
2   2014-01-04 17:20:12 2014-01-04 17:20:02 23.75
3   2014-01-04 17:25:12 2014-01-04 17:25:02 23.75
4   2014-01-04 17:30:12 2014-01-04 17:30:02 23.69
5   2014-01-04 17:35:12 2014-01-04 17:35:02 23.75
```

Database 2:
t0000 t/m t2100 are the timestamps for the forecast temperatures

```
day         created_on          t0000   t0300   t0600   t0900   t1200   t1500   t1800   t2100
2014-01-12  2014-01-13 00:00:10 2.52    4.24    5.83    6.51    7.58    7.55    6.23    0.34
2014-01-13  2014-01-14 02:00:10 4.31    6.54    6.32    8.28    9.13    8.46    5.38    4.13
2014-01-14  2014-01-14 23:00:08 4.18    2.58    2.95    8.24    7.54    6.7 4.96    4
2014-01-15  2014-01-14 23:00:08 3.58    2.77    2.64    2.53    4.56    4.56    4.54    4.58
```

I've come up with the database2 structure, as each day get's updated 8 times a day.
And it's not only one day of information I receive, but I receive multiple day updates each 8 times a day, this produces to much rows, so now I rewrite the column each time I receive an update. This solution saved me bigtime in rows (as I like to keep some history), but now gives me another puzzle to deal with: joining them together.

I'm out for my sql magic, hoping there is some greater power out there... somewhere ;)

Comment: A couple of questions.  First, when you write "two different databases," do you mean "two different tables in the same database?" This is important because you can `JOIN` multiple tables in a query.  Second, why do you say eight observations per day produces too many rows?  Why not one row per observation?

Comment: Another question: what is the purpose of your `created_on` columns? Are they just for logging? Or do they relate somehow to the time of the observations?

Comment: No, they are different databases. I've made one database called "2014_temperature". Alle one-wire temperature devices get added and logged automatically to a separate table, who's table is the ROM name.
With some code, I can find all the ROM tables, and display them in a graph.   
It's easy to work with, but if this is not the right choice, I'm willing to rethink this over.
The created_on is indeed the timestamp of adding the data, and the day  column is used as unique key for reading.

Comment: Separate tables for information from identical instruments is not usually considered good design. It would be wiser to put a `station` column in a single table. If you do that it will be easier to deal with new or missing instruments. Before you add a separate "day" column, please consider looking up the concept of index range scan.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you need a `temperature` table with each row containing:

```
  station      the location name of the measurement, e.g. BOS, LHR, etc.
  timestamp    the time of the measurement 
  temp         (FLOAT) the measurement
```

Each time a new measurement arrives you need to insert a new row.  You can use a composite of (`station`, `timestamp`) for the primary key on this table.

To summarize by day, you simply do

```
 SELECT station, DATE(timestamp), 
        MIN(temp) AS low,
        AVG(temp) AS avg,
        MAX(temp) AS high
   FROM temperature
  GROUP BY station, DATE(timestamp)
  ORDER BY station, DATE(timestamp)
```

This pattern for querying can produce all sorts of interesting summaries.

Don't worry about too many rows in your observation table.  Reports like this take well under a minute even when summarizing decades of measurements.

I happen to have been working on this problem lately. Here is a writeup.
http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/

An excellent source of worldwide historical data is here: http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/download.phtml

Comment: Maybe my separation of data in different databases is not so good for retrieving. But I'm thinking about an optimal solution.
maybe a better one:  
1 database with columns for:  
timestamp - sensor1, sensor2, sensor3.    The only thing I'm wondering about is how the forecast data should be updated.

Comment: My current data structure for the forecast allows me te get multiple days of information ahead, and every 3 hours I can update the values to get more accurate data. If I will do this in one table with the sensors, I think I should filter the old forecast entry, delete the old forecast entry, and add a new one otherwise I will be having "current" data 5 day's in the past in the table. hmmm, good food for thought.

Comment: MySQL has a nice `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` command that might simplify your forecast table maintenance.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I'm using this ON Duplicate already as I'm updating the current forecast data each 3 hours. I'm going to rewrite my current database.
To not overwhelm the openweathermap site, I'm sticking with 3 hour updates, but I'll make a private cache, that I'll use to update the forecast each 5 minutes. When done, I'll report back.

Comment: I've rebuild the database structure and now all sensors are in one database. It's much easier to code, but I'm thinking about another problem in the future... It's going to be crowded in the table when we hit 2015. Thank you for your time!